# "Objects are not valid as a React child" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api, mern

the data is not displayed by REACT and the following error is received: "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

The records from MongoDB collection are fetched and gathered in an array of objects. then I use the .map() function to produce the array of

elemens to be rendered by the Display component. Each

element includes the  component which receives two props (firstName and age)

i do not see where is my mistake...

thanx for help!

SingleRecord.js:

```
    const SingleRecord = (firstName, age) => {    
        return (
        <li className="singe-record">
            {firstName} is {age} years old.
        </li>
        );
    }
    
    export default SingleRecord;
```

Display.js:

```
    function Display() {
        const [records, setRecords] = useState();
        const dataArray = [];

        const fetchRecords = () => {
            fetch('http://localhost:3001/users')
            .then(async response => {
                const isJson = await response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('application/json');           
                const data = isJson ? await response.json() : null;

            for (const elem of data) {
            let elemObj = {
                _id: elem._id, 
                firstName: elem.firstName,
                age: elem.age};
                dataArray.push(elemObj);
            }
                setRecords(dataArray);

                // check for error response
            if (!response.ok) {
                    // get error message from body or default to response status
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;
            return Promise.reject(error);
            }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There was an error!', error);
            });
        }

        useEffect(() => {  
            fetchRecords();
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        }, []);

        if (!records) {
            return null;
        }

        const LI = records.map(elem => {
                    let fn = elem.firstName;
                    let ageee = elem.age;
                    return <li><SingleRecord firstName={fn} age={ageee} /></li>
        })

        return (
            <div className="records-display">
            <h2>Records:</h2>
            <ul className ="records-list">
                {LI}
            </ul>      
            </div>
        );
    }
```

app.js (backend):

```
    const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
    const uri = "...hidden...";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
    const database = client.db('holdocsDB');
    const records = database.collection('records');

    app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
        const cursor = await records.find();  
        const results = await cursor.toArray();
        res.send(results);         
    })
        
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        next(createError(404));
    });
    
    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        // set locals, only providing error in development
        res.locals.message = err.message;
        res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

        // render the error page
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json('error');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because LI is an array, so you would get the same error if you did something like:

{['foo', 'bar']}

change it to this and give it a try:

```
    return (
        <div className="records-display">
        <h2>Records:</h2>
        <ul className ="records-list">
            {records.map(elem => {
                let fn = elem.firstName;
                let ageee = elem.age;
                return <li><SingleRecord firstName={fn} age={ageee} /></li>
             })}
        </ul>      
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: thanx for your response, @terpinmd! unfortunately it still doesn't work and I get the same error after making the changes that you proposed

Comment: solved! in SingleRecord.js component code instead of passing the literal values as arguments, I had to pass "(props)" and use the props as 'props.firstName' and 'props.age'.